# Public Service Announcement: Don't edit out links from spam posts

Tags: discussion, flagging

Twice in a row today: posts flagged as spam, with no spammy content in them because someone edited out their links.

**Please, don't!**

Flag spam as spam and let the moderators handle it. I understand the (good) intentions behind the edits, however by removing the links you are just adding an additional step to our work, because we need to go check the post history to validate your flag.

And, technically, you are turning a spam post into a "not an answer" post, something which we mods normally stay away from and which the spam flag might not be applicable.

Thanks!

Comment: What about an edit that makes the link not work?

Comment: Do not edit spam, period. Flag it.

Comment: Hey, good to know. I had this habit but I didn't now it had this impact. I won't edit those out anymore.

Comment: How evil is the spam? Is it "Will install malware on your computer" bad, or "Links to an mundane ad for tourism" bad? On skeptics.SE, some really evil posts have a median lifespan of [two hours](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4324/require-questions-about-the-holocaust-to-receive-moderator-approval-before-publi)